# Configure ASP.NET MVC Through Web.Config

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to publish a ASP.NET app to my web host. I can publish it but the app doesn't work. It's seems like ASP.NET MVC isn't configured. My web host's management pages simply allows me to define an app but has no configuration options. They're telling me I need to configure ASP.NET MVC through my web.config file. However, every guide I looked at shows how to do this through IIS. Which I don't have access to.

How do I configure ASP.NET MVC through my web.config file?

The error I'm getting when I navigate to my app is.

> HTTP Error 404.7 - Not Found
> The request filtering module is configured to deny the file extension.

Thanks

Comment: The `web.config` file is located along side the other folders that were produced when you published the app. You likely had to upload all of these folders to your web host. Just open that `web.config` and make the changes before you upload it to your web host.